# Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am trying to run script which uses XML/LibXML package.
But, XML/LibXML package is already installed. I ran following command:
perl -MXML::LibXML -e 1. it did not give any output, that means this package is installed.

when i ran my script. Following error occured.

> Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
>   .). BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

One more point to note is there is no directory "5.8.8" under /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/

Please suggest to overcome this issue.

Comment: What's the shebang in your script? What output do you get from `which perl`? What output do you get from `perl -MXML::LibXML\ 999`?

Comment: Re "*One more point to note is there is no directory "5.8.8" under /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/*", That's not likely to be a problem.

Comment: Please provide the output of `perl -MXML::LibXML -le'print "#!".$^X; print $INC{"XML/LibXML.pm"}'` and the first line of your script.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities:

- You have two installs of `perl` and you script is using the "wrong" one.

  Either install XML::LibXML using the `perl` used by the script, or replace the script's shebang (`#!`) line with the output of the following:

  ```
  perl -MXML::LibXML -le'print "#!".$^X'
  ```
- Differences in the environment.

  If XML::LibXML was installed in a nonstandard directory, it could be that `PERL5LIB` was used to communicate this to `perl` when you executed your test, but not when you run the script.
- A permission issue.

  This isn't very likely.

  If the script is run as the same user as your test, it's not a permission issue.

  If it is a permission issue, make sure the library directory is accessible to the user executing the script.